# How to show multiple images at once with a jspsych plugin?

Tags: gorilla, jspsych

I am coding in Gorilla and try to show multiple images at once using a JsPsych plugin.

Currently I am using the plugin jsPsychImageButtonResponse as follows:

```
var trial = {
    type: jsPsychImageButtonResponse,
    stimulus: [aURL, bURL, cURL],
    choices: [aURL, bURL, cURL],
};
```

I would like to show three cards (named aURL, bURL, cURL) and make the participants click on one of them.

I uploaded the images in the resources tab on Gorilla and referred to them like this:

```
// URL's for images
var aURL = gorilla.stimuliURL('a.png');
var bURL = gorilla.stimuliURL('b.png');
var cURL = gorilla.stimuliURL('c.png');  

// Create an array containing all the URL's for our required stimuli
var images = [];
images.push(aURL);
images.push(bURL);
images.push(cURL);
```

Any help is welcome.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is going wrong? Are the images not showing up?

Comment: I don't manage to show the three stimuli simultaneously... Only one by one